# Create date of a specific weekday two weeks before the current week

Tags: sql, date, h2

I'm trying to create a SQL statement (in [H2 Dialect](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html)) that creates a DATE which is 
the tuesday in the "week-of-year" that is two weeks from the current week.

For example, given CURRENT_DATE() returns 2014-04-23, the date that I want would be 2014-04-08, which is the Tuesday in the week that is two weeks before the week the Date "2014-04-23" is in.

How can I express this with H2's Date and Time functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) I would do it like this

```
DECLARE @date DATE = GETDATE();
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,3-DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@date),DATEADD(WEEK,-2,@date))
```

Where '3' represents day of the week (Tuesday) and '-2' represents subtracting two weeks.

So now in [h2](/questions/tagged/h2) it is very similar

```
SELECT DATEADD('DAY',3-DAY_OF_WEEK(CURRENT_DATE()),DATEADD('WEEK',-2,CURRENT_DATE()))
```

Comment: That works great, thanks! Just a little note: your second (h2) statement is missing a closing parenthesis.